# Custom Tab Bar with StoryBoard and Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, storyboard

I've designed my iPhone app in Photoshop and now I have all the PNG files of my project.
I have Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5. What I would like to do is to customize the tab bar of my app. I've done the things on storyboard, but I do not know how to implement the PNG tab bar in the storyboard. I've written the source code of the customized tab bar, but when I run it in the simulator it doesn't display the `ViewController` which IS already done on the StoryBord.

So, the question is: how to attach the new tab bar design with Xcode Storyboard?

Comment: See the customization APIs available to you in Apple's documentation for `UITabBar`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 2):

If you've subclassed the `UITabBar` and written code to customize it, you'll need to set the tab bar's class to your subclass in the identity inspector. Click the tab bar in your storyboard and set it's class:

[image]

Then it should begin using your custom code.